# does using asyncio loops inside threads decrease performance

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

i am creating a system where i have to query a distant server periodically multiple times, about 10000 times a second. it is a bit a lot but it is still experimental and i won the server so no issues with exceeding load or anything.

how i did that is spin up 50 processes and each process spins up about 200 threads with each running a loop over 2 asyncio tasks forever.

the loop looks like this

```
        async def getDataPeriodically(item):
            while True:
                self.getNewData(item)
                await asyncio.sleep(replayInterval)

        entriesLoop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        entriesLoop.create_task(getDataPeriodically("X"))
        entriesLoop.create_task(getDataPeriodically("Y"))
        entriesLoop.run_forever()
```

the issue i had is that although the `replayInterval` is set to 0.5 second or 1 second even, self.getNewData wouldn't finish the HTTP request on time . sometimes it finishes 10 seconds after and sometimes even 2 minutes after.

i would like to know if running an `asyncio` loop inside a thread decreases the efficiency or opposes the concurrency logic of the thread ?

Comment: Somewhat off topic to your asked question, but could you change `getNewData()` to hang or update a local variable that is the condition for reacquiring new data? If the local variable is an object, the thread can see it, by using memory addressing.

Comment: @deseuler what do you mean by condition for reacquiring new data, a check to whether do the HTTP calls or not?

Comment: There really isn't much point using threads to run several asyncio loops. Both threads and asyncio use a single core (due to the GIL), so in effect all you do is add 200 schedulers. On top, the thread scheduler works best for *low* concurrency (dozens) and the asyncio scheduler works best for *high* concurrency (hundreds to thousands+) – you are using both at their *worst* scale.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i am currently doing that benchmark in fact, running less threads with more asyncio tasks instead of the inverse. and i think it works best that way.

Comment: You might want to skip threads entirely. Just run one ``asyncio`` loop of 400 tasks. It might even be able to handle (much!) more than that. The main bottleneck is how closely the tasks should happen together, but if that's the limit then you need more processes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change `getNewData()`, you do not need the await calls.
Threads can update object attributes directly, so you can pass in a dictionary (or other object) and monitor a specific attribute.

This doesnt answer your question about `asyncio`, but may help with your overall problem?

```
    ....

    def getNewData(self, obj):
        #Request data

        #Once data is received
        obj['dataReceived'] = True

    ....

    def getDataPeriodically(item):
        obj = {'dataReceived': False}
        while True:
            self.getNewData(item, obj)
            while not obj['dataReceived']: #Wait for getNewData to receive data
                pass

            #Do whatever with data

            obj['dataReceived'] = False #Prep for next HTTP request

thread = threading.Thread(target=getDataPeriodically, args=(item,))
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
```